# How to load in a Grails, the external CSS that within a JAR dependency

Tags: grails

I have a Grails project how I need to load a CSS how is located in a Jar dependency. I've looked for resources plugin but it not respond to my issue.

In my jar dependency, my css is located in public folder 
public/styles/bootstrap/**.css

What is the process to declare in grails an external css, "my css is declared on xxx.jar" ?

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> What is the process to declare in grails an
>   external css, "my css is declared on xxx.jar" ?

There is no such declaration. Keep in mind that css files are something that has to be published on some URL so the browser can download and apply it.